# leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I've created a map with Leaflet and jQuery and I wanted to add Clustergroups to my Markers but I am getting the error : `leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`

Here my code:

```
  $.get(url).done(function (data) {


            var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var title = "hi";

                let marker = L.marker(([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude]));
                marker.bindPopup(title);
                markers.addLayer(marker);
               
            }
            mymap.addLayer(markers);

        }
```

I tried to search for the problem and found this https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/724 but the problem was never answered. Also i read about different types of problems that it is maybe the problem of jQuery that it cannot define the variables. But I dont't know where my mistake could be, can anyone see it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are useing twice `()` in marker creation.

Change:

```
let marker = L.marker(([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude]));
```

to:

```
let marker = L.marker([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude]);
```

Comment: unfortunately  I am still getting the error

Comment: Okabe have you checked if `data[i].latitude` has a value?

Comment: Yes I did the problem is in this line `var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();` I get the error but I dont know  what to do

Comment: The link I provided has the same issue one  commentator had a brief text on the problem but he did not elaborate in this